# Passing sensible data through ProcessBuilder

Tags: java

I am trying to communicate to an external console application from my java program, and I need to pass it a password.

My question is, it is secure to pass the password in plain text within ProcessBuilder() list of arguments? I mean, somebody could intercept that message? What would be a safer way to accomplish that?

Thank you

```
ArrayList<String> lstArgs = new ArrayList<String>();        
lstArgs.add("program.exe");
lstArgs.add("password");       

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(lstArgs);
pb.start();
```

Comment: I expect if your password is hardcoded like in your example, someone could pull it out of the bytecode of your program.

Comment: *"is, it is secure to pass the password in plain text within ProcessBuilder() "* - No, but what choice do you have...Also, on Windows, it would be possible to actually determine the parameters that were passed to a process...making it even less secure...

Comment: Anyone who can read the password from the command can also read the string from your process in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not secure to pass a password in plaintext to another process.   And definitely insecure to pass it as a commandline argument - ordinary users can read command line arguments without any special privileges (e.g. the output of ps or top or the equivalent in Windows).

Finally, avoid capturing and holding passwords in String variables.   Use an array of characters, and overwrite the contents as soon as you no longer need it.  The problem with String is that you don't control when the memory is reclaimed, and you cannot overwrite the contents (String is immutable).

What's a better way to do this?   How about creating a programmatic interface (API) to program.exe, and passing the info in through a call, or a socket.  How about passing the password in a user-only-readable file and giving the name or handle to that file.

If you cannot change program.exe, then you will be forced to use the insecure approach.